Make Flask and Discord.py library communicate
I have a small project on my mind but I cannot solve one problem. I have two parts of my project, Flask App and Discord Bot, hereinafter referred to as app.py and bot.py. App.py uses sync programming and bot.py async. The thing is I have this specific function in bot.py:
async def get_dm_attachments(user_id):
  user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
  if not user:
    return None
  dm = user.dm_channel
  if dm == None:
    dm = await user.create_dm()

  reslist = []

  async for message in dm.history(limit=10000):
    if message.attachments:
      for attachment in message.attachments:
        reslist.append(attachment)
  
  return reslist

This function is meant to retrieve all atachments from DMs with a specific user specified by user id. I want to be able to call this function from app.py and retrieve the data from it.
I tried running the async func with asyncio.run(), but that didn't work and I think it's because the function itself is useless until the bot is running, therefore if only executing the function separately from the rest of the script I get an error. So I need to have running instance of bot.py in which I can run the function any time.
I also tried websocket but I couldn't make it listen on bot.py while letting the rest of the script operate normally.
Threading was also one of the options I found online and yeah it might solve some problems but I couldn't make it work. I believe it's the same reason why I just can't run it with asyncio.run()
I have a working SQL database via mysql wamp server if that could be any useful.


App.py uses sync programming and bot.py async.

I really, really recommend you migrate from Flask to Quart. Quart is exactly like Flask, but rewritten in async. This will spare you a lot of headaches in the future.
Also, make sure that you handle None whenever you use the get_dm_attachments() function. You might forget and only expect a reslist to be returned.
